# operations with elements in list of list in python

Tags: python, list

This is my list:

```
volume = [['1.986', '3000'], ['1.987', '2000'], ['1.986', '700'],['1.987', '4000']]
```

How can I get the sum of volume[1] when volume[0] is the same price?

```
results = [['1.986', '3700'], ['1.987', '6000']]
```

Comment: Do you know what a dictionary does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Groupby statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636008/python-groupby-statement)

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries would be a good data structure to use here. The default dict holds unique strings as the keys and assumes empty values are 0 because I set it to be based off of int.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for v in volume:
    d[v[0]] += int(v[1])
print d
```

If you need a list afterwards you can use a list comprehension:

`list_version = [[key, value] for key,value in d]`

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I'd unpack the tuple in the `for` loop though: `for price, qty in volume: ...`

Comment: Thanks for useful help!